# Can anything be done to limit an Eventbrite event to the invited individuals only?

Tags: eventbrite

Can anything be done to limit an Eventbrite event to the invited individuals only?

I realize that there are settings which cause an event to be "by invitation only".  Then you send an invitation to the particular email addresses you want.  Only they can use the registration page. (Others will get a message "this event is by invitation only").  That's great!  So far so good.

But the problem is, the person who received the invitation can register a completely different  (uninvited)  individual to be the attendee.  All the attendee fields are writeable:  Name, email address,  mailing address etc.

It let's you change the email address and even asks if you wish to send an invitation email to the new email address.  The new individual gets an email saying:  "An order for xxxx was purchased for you by: yyyy"  which is not desirable in our case.

The invited individual has a "my Account" area with his/her information (name, email, etc) filled in.  But the attendee information is different info to be filled in (as opposed to being drawn from the info in the account area)

Answer (score 0):

Configuring your Order Form to "collect only basic information" should ensure that each registration email and attendee email are identical:
http://help.eventbrite.com/customer/en_us/portal/articles/426121-collect-information-from-attendees

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see that.... P.S. except if we use "collect only basic information" I believe then we can't have any extra questions (via "add a question"). 

If I'm wrong about that let us know. Meantime, our plan is to tell people that they are not allowed to fill in a different attendee. We'll manualy scan the registrations and if they did, then we'll phone them up and fix accordingly.